# Empty Json Array is received on Post

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have an MVC application that is calling a web api to pass some data.

**MVC-code**

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> StudentViewModels_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> studentviewmodels)
    {
        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            string  baseUrl = "http://localhost:51514/api/Students";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            JArray postData = new JArray();
            //postData.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
            foreach(StudentViewModel student in studentviewmodels)
            {
                postData.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));
            }
           // call the web-api and pass the data
           System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(postData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

        // this will return new data
        //return Json("");
    }
```

here is picture of the data that is in **postData** variable before it is sent

[image]

However, when the call reaches the Api, the  Json array is empty.

**Web-api**

```
    public  IHttpActionResult Students_Create(JArray inputData)
    {

        var students = new List<Student>();

        for (int i = 1; i<inputData.Count; i++)
        {
            var tempStudent = new Student();
            tempStudent = (Student)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputData[i].ToString());
            students.Add(tempStudent);
        }

        // Will keep the inserted entitites here. Used to return the result later.
        var entities = students;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var northwind = new StudentEntities())
            {
                foreach (var student in students)
                {
                    // Create a new Student entity and set its properties from the posted StudentViewModel.
                    var entity = new Student
                    {
                        Studentid = student.Studentid,
                        Firstname = student.Firstname,
                        Lastname = student.Lastname,
                        Age = student.Age
                    };
                    // Add the entity.
                    northwind.Students.Add(entity);
                    // Store the entity for later use.
                    entities.Add(entity);
                }
                // Insert the entities in the database.
                northwind.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(db.Students);
    }
```

picture of **inputData** variable

[image]

Any ideas as to why this is happening?. thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm a little shaky on some of this, but have you tried `await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))`?  The framework should serialize `postData` for you - maybe you're serializing it into a string and then the framework is serializing the string again, and then the receiving API might interpret what you are sending as a string rather than a JArray???  Just a shot in the dark...

Comment: I get the error **cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'string'**

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but more of an observation of the code you provided. You don't appear to be calling your `Students_Create` method anywhere in the `StudentViewModels_Create`. Which leads me to believe you are passing the returned result of `StudentViewModels_Create` to `Students_Create` which will not work since `StudentViewModels_Create` returns an empty Json object (`return Json("")`).

Comment: The StudentViewModels_Create method is called by the Add_student page, i am just showing you data that is going to be passed to the api

Comment: Can you show how the StudentViewModel is defined? Maybe you're missing necessary contractual meta data in the class declarations. For example, the built in .Net `DataContractJsonSerializer` requires the class to be declared with `[DataContract]` and subsequent members declared with `[DataMember]`. Maybe your `JavaScriptSerializer` requires something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Json Array. this piece of code in the **MVC-code** section

```
        JArray postData = new JArray();
        //postData.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
        foreach(StudentViewModel student in studentviewmodels)
        {
            postData.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));
        }
```

when i pass the array through the serializer

```
       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(postData);
       var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

       // pass the data to the api
       System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, stringContent);
```

the json varaible only contains an empty array, so what is passed to the api, is an empty array. hence why i was only getting an empty array.

I decided to try an ArrayList instead of a JArray, then passed it through the serializer and it worked.  I am not 100% certain as to why this solved the issue, i am still researching for a concrete reason.

```
        ArrayList postData = new ArrayList();
        postData.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
        foreach (StudentViewModel student in studentviewmodels)
        {
            postData.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));
        }
```